How can I recover lost partitions?
My primary SSD has its boot sector erased, thus all partitions are not recognized by the computer. I can't boot the operating system on it, and I am currently using a spare HDD with bad sectors, and the partitions aren't recognized by the OS I am currently using.
But the partitions are there, the drive is not formatted, and I can see the partitions just fine using a hex editor, and DiskGenius has easily recognized these partitions, but the problem is I can't save the partition table, the functionality is locked behind a DiskGenius paywall and requires a registration, which costs a lot of money.
I got into this situation by running SDelete or cipher /w:C:, at this point I don't know which caused this, but I am pretty sure it was SDelete because I ran SDelete without arguments and I ran SDelete /p 1 -z D:, I guess the second command is malformed because it first tries to zero write "physical disk 1" which gets access denied and then it tries to zero write D:: (notice that there are two colons) which is not found and raises the same access denied error.
Turns out I shouldn't add the colon :, the argument should be only the letter and the command should have been SDelete /p 1 -z D. I originally wanted to overwrite all deleted files with zeros on an active disk partition, I intended to zero writing all the file records marked in NTFS master file table as unused, so that the disk defragmentation software ignores the deleted files and reuse the space used by the deleted files. I want to leave the used files unharmed.
I have learned everything from this Wikipedia article on NTFS and followed this documentation to write a completely working NTFS MFT parser in Python, it is as efficient as I can make it, but it can be much more efficient if I wrote it in C++, but unfortunately my C++ skills are not there yet. I guess I have to try to rewrite the program in C++ once the partition is recovered.
Please tell me what I have to do to reconstruct the boot sector so that the partitions can be read. The master file table and all files marked as InUse are not damaged.

Update: I have fixed the partition table and now the partitions are found and accessible by operating systems on other disks. But the disk still cannot be booted directly.
I fixed the partition table by using testdisk, following the guide I selected the drive and then I selected the first partition table type option ([Intel]) and then I ran the search, it searched for well over 50% of the disk and haven't found the partition at all.
I tried the search several times, no partition was found. Weird, DiskGenius partition recovery found the partitions almost instantaneously.
So I selected the second partition table type ([EFI GPT]) and then proceeded to analyze the disk, the partition is found immediately, but somehow testdisk doesn't stop scanning after the last cylinder, the scanned cylinder index jumps to 121601 immediately, but the last cylinder index is 121601.
The program becomes unresponsive and stuck at 99%. And I cannot stop the scanning.
I don't know after how many times I hit the stop button by pressing Enter it finally knew to stop.
So I write the partition table to the disk and rebooted. And now the partition is back. I can access the partition but I still cannot boot from it directly somehow.
I get "Bootmgr is missing Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart" error when I boot the SSD directly. bcdboot doesn't fix the problem. mbrfix64 doesn't fix the problem.
But interestingly I can boot the OS on the disk if I use Windows Boot Manager on another disk and use the entry in that bootmgr for the OS on the SSD.
Using this method the OS is booted successfully without problems. I am using the main OS right now. There are no problems with it but I cannot boot it directly because bootmgr is missing.
I read I can use the following commands to fix this:
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd

But naturally bootrec.exe isn't available for download. I have found bootsect.exe on my Windows 10 installation iso instead.
I used the following command but apparently it isn't working:
PS C:\Windows\System32> H:\boot\bootsect.exe /nt60 C: /force /mbr
Target volumes will be updated with BOOTMGR compatible bootcode.

C: (\\?\Volume{a9e2494b-f9aa-11ee-a1d8-806e6f6e6963})

    Updated NTFS filesystem bootcode.  The update may be unreliable since the
    volume could not be dismounted during the update:
        Access is denied.

\??\PhysicalDrive1

    Bootcode is only updated on MBR partitioned disks.  A different
    partitioning scheme is used on this disk.
Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes.

What do I do now?

I have no clue how this can be fixed without using recovery software. It definitely is not going to be as easy as making a few hex edits. Are the partitions gone in your partition editing tools too? If not, then a simple mbrfix (https://sysint.no/en/mbrfix/) may be enough to restore it. especially mbrfix /fixmbr

If only the boot sector is destroyed, running Startup Repair might fix it. Don't try to do it yourself.

Backup before you do anything. It's been years but I think I have used testdisk in this situation before. It's worth a shot.

I have no idea how this question got a downvote, I absolutely have shown more research effort than most people on this site who posted questions, they would probably just have paid money to let others handle things, I have no money and so I do everything by myself and thus I learned a lot of things.

I just downvoted your posting. It is a complete mess content-wise. The explanation does not fit into a comment.

You could have contacted DiskGenius and asked if they would let you have a one-time licence for, say, $15. It's always worth asking that sort of thing, the worst that can happen is they say no.

@ΞένηΓήινος - I can’t track what the current state your hdd is in, if you can boot to windows, you should recover what you can and reinstall Windows. Modify the disk your trying to recover was a mistake now you have no way to reverse anything you have done. This question needs to be modified to focus on relevant details.

It is always a good idea to mention the operating system used instead of letting others guess. This applies particularly for questions of boot repair.

Why don't you try Startup Repair?

I have fixed the second problem. Turns out the solution is extremely simple.
I did the following to fix the boot problem. I first converted the partition table type to MBR using DiskGenius and then mark the system partition active.
The OS for some reason is installed using a GPT partition table, and there was a hidden system partition a few hundred megabytes in size, that was the EFI boot partition and I am unable to recover it.
By converting the partition table to MBR the BOOTMGR has been recognized. As I stated previously there was an error saying "BOOTMGR is missing".
Maybe the BOOTMGR is fixed by the command I previously ran (bootsect /nt60 E: /force /mbr, I ran it on the spare OS), but the effect only applies when I change the partition table to MBR.
Anyway the BOOTMGR shows up, but I can't boot the Windows installed on my SSD now, it shows a blue screen that says
C:\Windows\system32\winload.exe 0xc000000e.
I tried to fix the problem myself, I have already installed EasyBCD, so I opened it and I clicked "BCD Deployment" then selected the SSD partition and clicked "Install BCD", then I clicked "Write MBR", then added the OS on the SSD to the boot menu, and finally I performed "Re-create/repair boot files" action in "BCD backup/repair" section.
And it worked. This makes the disk bootable on its own. The BOOTMGR is installed on the SSD now.


My primary SSD has its boot sector erased, thus all partitions are not recognized by the computer.

Technically possible only in a rare corner case. The term boot sector commonly stands for the first sector of a partition or a volume.
Deleting the boot sector of one partition does not affect the readability of other partitions. The skeleton what holds all partitions together is the partition table that can be found in the MBR (master boot record) or the GPT (GUID partition table). The corner case is a disk device without any partition table at the beginning, starting directly with the boot sector of a partition, also called "superfloppy".

I can't boot the operating system on it, and I am currently using a spare HDD with bad sectors,

How does the hint regarding your spare HDD help? Are you using it as boot device, trying to express that due to bad sectors your repair installation is unstable?!

and the partitions aren't recognized by the OS I am currently using.

Again, this is pointing to a missing, defective or unreadable partition table.

But the partitions are there,

This is just a dubious statement in my eyes unless you explain how you come to this conclusion.

the drive is not formatted, and I can see the partitions just fine using a hex editor,

A normal hex editor does not provide proof if the partitions/volumes are healthy and usable in terms of what the chkdsk/fschk command would state.

I got into this situation by running SDelete or cipher /w:C:, at this point I don't know

The Sdelete command operate on files on folders. Using it in this mode does not require altering your NTFS boot sector (assuming the file system is NTFS, based on your NTFS remarks) The same applies for cleaning the free space. There is no need to modify the boot sector either when cleaning free space in NTFS.
As for the cipher command the link appears to be broken.
If you wrote a NTFS parser this is an impressive job but I don't see how that relates to your problem. This is beyond your case description.
Summary:
The subject of your posting now changed completely. What started as a data recovery issue, where the solution is definitively outlined in another generic superuser article now has become an posting about repairing the bootability of a disk.
I would recommend (not being the autority!) to post your repair questions regarding bootability in a separate question. But maybe there is already a generic superuser thread to this issue as well.

To repair your installation, here is the absolute minimum you need to know:
There are two commonly used boot methods for Windows and Linux machines.
The old one is based upon code in the MBR (see my other posting).
There is code in the MBR that is dectecting the active primary partition and calling the boot code in there.
Under linux there is more freedom with regards to the location of the boot code although everything starts with the MBR.
With the replacement of the old school bios by the newer UEFI ones things changed. A new boot method was introduced using a specialised "EFI boot partition".
Nevertheless the UEFI BIOS typically provides the old school boot method as a service. That is called CSM ("compatbility service module").
By checking your BIOS boot settings you can gather the information how your BIOS is booting. Various settings may be available like "UEFI boot only" or "legacy boot (use CSM) only" or "allow CSM when UEFI boot fails" or the like.
If there are no UEFI related switches you probably don't have a UEFI mainboard.
All repair steps depend on this information.
Unfortunately my knowledge ends here - I am only booting in CSM mode.

About your update:

Bootcode is only updated on MBR partitioned disks.  A different
partitioning scheme is used on this disk.

You are trying to write a MBR boot loader to a GPT partitioned disk. This is incorrect.
What partition scheme was on your SSD before the boot sector was erased, MBR or GPT? You need to restore the same partition scheme.
If MBR, then you shouldn't have chosen [EFI GPT] in testdisk, you should have continued with [Intel]. Why it didn't find any partitions is an another question.
If GPT, then you should use bcdboot and/or bcdedit to restore GPT boot loader. Why it didn't work is an another question. What parameters you used, what was the output of the command?
Also, did you restore all the partitions? In most cases there is more than one, and in most cases you need all of them to boot successfully.
